# Как адаптировать сайт под мобильные устройства?

Tags: html, css

Как адаптировать сайт под все мобильные устройства?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для адаптации используют `@media` запросы `CSS`. Синтаксис такой:

```
@media(Условие){
стили
}
```

Например,

```
@media(max-width: 992px){
/*Стили, на устройствах с максимальной ширеной экрана 992 пикселя и меньше */
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
/*Стили, на устройствах с максимальной ширеной экрана 768 пикселей и меньше */ 
}

@media(max-width: 500px){
/*Стили, на устройствах с максимальной ширеной экрана 500 пикселей и меньше */
}
```

Это стандартная сетка из bootstrap. Почитать про эту библиотеку можете [тут](https://webref.ru/layout/bootstrap4) Можно  подключив ее к сайту и немного переписать верстку, но это тяжелая библиотека и там много лишнего. Многие от нее отказываются. Почитать про медиа-запросы можно, например, [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) или [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media).

Еще стоит почитать про подходы к адаптивной верстке mobile-first и desktop-first. Сравнивают их во многих статьях, например, [тут](https://webmedia31.ru/articles/mobile-first).

Также стоит отметить, что если вы используете медиа-запросы, то их надо группировать, чтобы Ваш сайт лучше работал. И тут два варианта:

1. Писать только один экземпляр медиа-запроса, как выше и в конце файла `css`, что не всегда удобно.
2. Использовать сборщики с предустановленными плагинами, которые автоматизируют рутинные задачи верстки (подключение и конвертация шрифтов, сжатие картинок, **группировка медиа-запросов**, подстановка префиксов для разных браузеров). Я использую для этого сборку [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) с плагином [gulp-group-css-media-queries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-group-css-media-queries) и некоторыми другими. Хороший гайд по настройке найдите в ютубе, сборок тьма. Есть еще сборщик [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), говорят он лучше, точно новее, но с ним не работал, так как привык к gulp.

Answer (score 1):

Варианта по идее только 2. Вы можете использовать поддомен для сайта и на нем размещать отдельную версию сайта, созданную для удобного просмотра на смартфонах. Или же, более оптимальный и менее затратный вариант - вы используете для этих целей CSS. А именно - медиа запросы. Суть в том, что например, при ширине окна браузера < 400px, можно изменять нужные вам стили, скрыть какие-то блоки, например, скрывать боковые блоки меню. А при ширине окна > 800px - отображать элементы, которые рассчитаны на десктопную версию шаблона. Гуглите в сторону медиа запросов, это очень полезная и нужная вещь, если вы хотите создать сайт с адаптивным и отзывчивым шаблоном!